# Ocelot Routing two different API's

Tags: .net, ocelot

I have two api's api A and api B and all controllers are the same for two APIs.

I want to redirect Api A if my request url includes client=A

Example : https://localhost:7259/api/login?client=A

I tried to add "client" to AddHeadersToRequest in Ocelot.json but it didn't work.

When I set it like this, it gave an error that there cannot be two of the same route.({everything})

```html
{
    "Routes": [
      {
        "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
        "DownstreamScheme": "http",
        "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
          {
            "Host": "localhost",
            "Port": 40411
          }
        ],
        "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
        "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH" ],
        "SwaggerKey": "APIA",
        "Key": "APIA",
        "RouteIsCaseSensitive": false,
        "Match": {
          "Key": "Client",
          "Value": "APIA"
        },
        "AddHeadersToRequest": {
          "client": "APIA"
        }
      },
      {
        "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
        "DownstreamScheme": "http",
        "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
          {
            "Host": "localhost",
            "Port": 53639
          }
        ],
        "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{everything}",
        "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH" ],
        "SwaggerKey": "APIB",
        "Key": "APIB",
        "RouteIsCaseSensitive": false,
        "Match": {
          "Key": "Client",
          "Value": "APIB"
        },
        "AddHeadersToRequest": {
          "client": "APIB"
        }
      }
    ],
    "GlobalConfiguration": {
      "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:7259/"
    }
  }
```

Do you have any recommendations ?